# What are required dependencies/dlls for Oracle ODP.net unmanaged 12.2 (Oracle.DataAccess.dll)?

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, odp.net

I am using **unmanaged** Oracle.DataAccess.dll having version (4.122.1.0).

However I do not want to install the Oracle client on each machine.

Can someone suggest dlls/files that I can copy with my .Net Executable, so that i do not have to install Oracle client?

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend to copy the DLL's manually.

Download the XCopy version you need

- **ODAC122010Xcopy_x64.zip** from [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html)
- **ODAC122010Xcopy_32bit.zip** from [32-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) and NuGet Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html)

Then you can simply install everything from command line like

```
install.bat odp.net4 c:\oracle myhome true
```

If you still prefer to make it manually, you can read the `install.bat` file. It copies folder `instantclient_12_2` and `odp.net4` plus running a few configuration changes in GAC and Registry.

Or as an alternative use the **ODP.NET Managed Driver**. This requires only a single DLL `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`